# How to Register-PSRepository for another user?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core

In this environment, users (theuser account) are not permitted to install PowerShell. An IT person runs on the users machine with an elevated administrative account (admuser account) and installs PowerShell Core.

How can the admuser use `Register-PSRepository` to create a PSRepository for the theuser account?

**Additional information:**

The IT (admin) user installs PowerShell Core and runs a script I created to Set-ExecutionPolicy, Enable-PSRemoting, Install-Module (several), and other actions to prepare the system for end user use. It should `Register-PSRepository` for one or more NuGet repos in order to install modules from our internal NuGet repos. However, `Register-PSRepository` only registers the repository for the currently logged in user which is the admin user. In addition, the modules should be installed with `-Scope CurrentUser` since the user account should be able to Update-Module without requiring an admin account.

How can the script be changed to cause Register-PSRepository for the user and not the currently logged in admin user? Is this a call for impersonation?

Comment: Have the admin user load the target user's registry hive using `reg.exe load HKU\<username> C:\Users\<username>\ntuser.dat`. Then specify a run-once command that runs the PowerShell CLI with the `Register-PSRepository` call via that hive's `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` key, which will run the next time the target user logs on.

Comment: @mklement0, when I try this command it returns, `ERROR: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: @lit, that means that the target user happens to logged on at the moment. You can only load the hive while they're logged off.

Comment: Note: This question [was discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426077/45375) on Meta SO, which resulted in temporary closure as off-topic, which was reversed. The - to me unwarranted - down-votes are likely the result of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/45375).

Comment: @mklement0, thank you for mentioning the `Meta effect`. That would seem to explain what happened here.

Comment: @mklement0, much has been said about making SO a welcoming and safe place, especially for new users. If SE or SO management were looking for things to improve, their first stop should be Meta. This cannot be said on Meta or the swords will begin swinging. DO NOT DELETE THIS COMMENT AGAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate your task, have the admin user, from an elevated session, load the target user's registry hive using `reg.exe load HKU\<username> C:\Users\<username>\ntuser.dat` and then specify a run-once command that runs the PowerShell CLI with the `Register-PSRepository` call via that hive's `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` key, which will run the next time the target user logs on.

- Put the following into a script (`.ps1`) file...
- ... and adapt it:

  - Specify the target username as the value of `$targetUser` (you could easily [*parameterize* the script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters)).
  - Replace the sample PowerShell command stored in `$commandLine` with your `Register-PSRepository` call.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Set the target user's username.
$targetUser = 'jdoe'

# Load the target user's registry hive.
# NOTE: Make sure that the user isn't currently logged on, 
#       otherwise this will fail.
$null = reg.exe load HKU\$targetUser C:\Users\$targetUser\ntuser.dat
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }

# Formulate the command line to run when the target 
# user logs in next (only once).
# Note: For simplicity, a simple Write-Output call is used here.
#       Substitute your Register-PSRepository call here.      
$cmdLine = '"{0}" -Command Write-Output \"Hello, world.\"; pause' -f (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path

# Create a registry value that makes the command line run 
# (visibly) when the target user logs in next time.
# Note: "PSRepoRegistration" is a self-chosen name.
$runOnceKey = "registry::HKEY_USERS\$targetUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
Set-ItemProperty -ErrorAction Stop $runOnceKey PSRepoRegistration $cmdLine
```